# Dependent data validation list's with only two raw data columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns whose data I want to input in a data validation list upon the selection of other validation list. And to do it, it's not suitable to have other auxiliar columns/tables other than the two mentioned ones. How would you approach it (see video illustration [here](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AmiLN1omLZEehepRybpvGtADX0otYw?e=bLbbb3))? 
Thank in advance.

Comment: Please report the issue in the question and not by linking from other sites

Comment: It's not "report from other site". It's a video in my cloud where I more easily show my issue.

Comment: So, what is your question? Put sample data to post and explain what you want to do? Show your effort.

Comment: And I 'showed my effort' by making a video where I more comprehnsively exhibit my issue. 
I have two columns whose data I want to input in a data validation list upon the selection of other validation list. And to do it, it's not suitable to have other auxiliar columns/tables other than the two mentioned ones. Check the link and you'll see exactly what kind of solution I'm looking for. Thanks.